# Need to parse two sessions at the same time with telethon on Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, telethon

i have some troubles with parsing two or more sessions at the same time with telethon. I have tried this:

```
class NewSession:
    def __init__(self, session_name):
        self.client = TelegramClient(session_name, api_id, api_hash)
        self.session_name = session_name

    async def pool(self):
        print("working with:", self.session_name)
        @self.client.on(events.NewMessage(outgoing=True))
        async def main(event):
            message = event.message.to_dict()
            msg_text = message['message']
            print(msg_text)

        try:
            await self.client.start()
            await self.client.run_until_disconnected()
        finally:
            await self.client.disconnect()


async def main():
    user = NewSession("321")
    user2 = NewSession("123")
    await user.pool()
    await user2.pool()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

But only one is working. Need help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is inside your `main` function. When you `await` for a coroutine to return it doesn't mean that the execution continues to the next expression. So, in your code the line `await user2.pool()` is going to be executed only when the `user.poll()` coroutines returns a value, this is when the session '321' is disconnected.

You need to run the tasks concurrently; you can use the function [asyncio.gather](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather). Reworking your `main`:

```py
async def main():
    user = NewSession("321")
    user2 = NewSession("123")
    await asyncio.gather(user.pool(), user2.pool())
```

Comment: That's working! Thank you. But can i create some storage and then add user.pool() to it?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you mean but you can pass all the values in a list to `asyncio.gather` using argument unpacking operator `*` over the list. `asyncio.gater(*[user.pool(), user2.pool()])`.

Comment: I'll try it, thank you